# How to make sure click is finalized?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I use the following code to query https://www.genecards.org/cgi-bin/carddisp.pl?gene=BSCL2

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
// vim: set noexpandtab tabstop=2:

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const fs = require('fs').promises;

const url = process.argv[2];

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    try {
        await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });
        const content = await page.content();
        //console.log(content);
        page.on('response', async response => {
            console.log("xxx" + response.url());
            response.buffer().then(function(data) {
                fs.writeFile('/tmp/response.json', data);
                //console.log(data);
            });
        });
        const linkHandlers = await page.$x('//div[@data-ga-category = "GeneHancer"]//a[@data-role = "show-all"]');
        if (linkHandlers.length > 0) {
            await linkHandlers[0].click();
        } else {
            throw new Error("Link not found");
        }

        const content1 = await page.content();
        //console.log(content1);
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
        process.exit(1);
    } finally {
        await browser.close();
    }
})();
```

The command is called in this way.

```
./main.js 'https://www.genecards.org/cgi-bin/carddisp.pl?gene=BSCL2'
```

But the line `console.log("xxx" + response.url());` is not called.

When I uncomment `//console.log(content1);`, the url `https://www.genecards.org/gene/api/data/Enhancers?geneSymbol=BSCL2` can be printed. But the printed content does not have all the entries shown in the `GeneHancer (GH) Regulatory Elements for BSCL2 Gene` table.

I think that the effect of `click()` has not completely taken place. How to wait for it to completely update the webpage? And how to show the content of `https://www.genecards.org/gene/api/data/Enhancers?geneSymbol=BSCL2` upon the response is received?

Answer (score 0):

After clicking the link you could check if the loading span is visible. If so you can wait until it's hidden. It could be something like this:

```
if ((await page.$$('#enhancerControllerComponent > div > div.ng-scope > div > div:nth-child(2) > span.gc-loading:not(.ng-hide)')).length) {
    await page.waitForSelector('#enhancerControllerComponent > div > div.ng-scope > div > div:nth-child(2) > span.gc-loading.ng-hide'));
}
```

You might need to improve these selectors. But that's the idea. Check if the loading state is visible and wait for it to be hidden.

Comment: I don't quite understand it. Why you use both $$ and waitForSelector? Why not just use `waitForSelector()`? How do you figure out what should be the argument of `waitForSelector()`? Thanks.

Comment: Is waitForNavigation more appropriate? `Bare in mind that if click() triggers a navigation event and there's a separate page.waitForNavigation() promise to be resolved, you may end up with a race condition that yields unexpected results. The correct pattern for click and wait for navigation is the following:` https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/1421

Comment: @user1424739 sure bit I didn't see a navigation occurring in your example there

Comment: So click is not navigation? What is considered as navigation?

Comment: @user1424739 Click is not necessarily a navigation. A link could be a navigation if it would have an `href` but here it´s making an ajax call. A navigation is when the page is "refreshed" completely.

Comment: Could you explain how the selector works for this case? This is still a proxy for checking click is finished. But it is not directly checking click.  There is not a direct way to check if click is finished?

Comment: You could also attach to the [response](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.20.0/docs/api.md#event-response) even and wait for the URL that click triggers, but I think this way is simpler.

Comment: The approach of monitoring `.ng-hide` does not work. It because this element can be changed before the actual URL is accessed `https://www.genecards.org/gene/api/data/Enhancers?geneSymbol=BSCL2`. Could you show me how to wait for `https://www.genecards.org/gene/api/data/Enhancers?geneSymbol=BSCL2` to be accessed? I also make the code indenpendent of the cookie file. So you should be able to run on your machine. Could you test your solution on you machine first to make it sure it works? Thanks.